# Fisher Expected Information for a Gaussian Process model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, information-theory, machine-learning, parameter-estimation

Suppose I have a two dimensional Gaussian process model (GP), defined by a squared exponential correlation function s.t: 
$$R(x_{i},x_{j}) = \exp\left(-\frac{|x_{i} - x_{j}|^2}{2}\right).$$
I am trying to evaluate Fisher Expected Information for the GP model, defined by:
$$I(\theta) = E\left[\left(\frac{\partial \log f(x;\theta)}{d \theta}\right)^2\right].$$

Comment: So wheres the parameter $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta$ here is the vector of parameters of a gaussian process model. 
A gaussian Process model is defined as follows:
$$f(x) = \Sigma_{j=1}^{p} f_{j}(x) \beta_{j} + Z(x)$$ where Z(x) is a gaussian process with zero mean and covariance defined by the above squared exponential function. Here, $\beta$ is not very important as a parameter. The parameters that i would like to know more about are the hyperparameters of the Gaussian Process, which in this case are the variance of the noise free signal and maybe the length-scale parameter.